# php multidimensional arrays. Change structure

Tags: php, arrays

Good day. I have the following problem:

I have an array.. I want to change stucture of it .. I do not want to put Array to parent Array if **object_id** not the same. How to do this? Array with **object_id** 917 should be level above like Arrays with index 1 and 2.

Is it possible at index 1 for example to have Array of arrays by different object_id ?

**object_type** it is like unique indexes.

**Initial array:**

```
$arr = [
    [
        'initiator_id' => 259, 'object_type' => 1, 'object_id' => 905,
        'date'         => '2021-11-16 06:24:16',
    ],
    [
        'initiator_id' => 259, 'object_type' => 1, 'object_id' => 917,
        'date'         => '2021-11-16 06:24:16',
    ],
    
    [
        'initiator_id' => 259, 'object_type' => 1, 'object_id' => 905,
        'date'         => '2021-11-16 04:54:54',
    ],
    [
        'initiator_id' => 259, 'object_type' => 1, 'object_id' => 905,
        'date'         => '2021-11-16 04:53:58',
    ],
    [
        'initiator_id' => 219, 'object_type' => 2, 'object_id' => 915,
        'date'         => '2021-11-16 04:53:58',
    ],
];
```

**Array:**

```
Array
(
    [object_type] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [initiator_id] => 259
                            [object_id] => 905
                            [date] => 2021-11-16 06:24:16
                            [activity] => added 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [initiator_id] => 259
                            [object_id] => 917 
                            [date] => 2021-11-16 06:24:16
                            [activity] => deleted
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [initiator_id] => 259
                            [object_id] => 905
                            [date] => 2021-11-16 04:54:54
                            [activity] => reopen
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [initiator_id] => 259
                            [object_id] => 905
                            [date] => 2021-11-16 04:53:58
                            [activity] => insert
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [initiator_id] => 219
                            [object_id] => 915
                            [date] => 2021-11-16 04:53:58
                            [activity] => change
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**php code:**

```
foreach($arr as $record) {
    foreach($record as $k => $v) {
        if($k == 'object_type') {
            $newArr['object_type'][$v][] = [
                'initiator_id' => $record['initiator_id'],
                'object_id' => $record['object_id'],
                'date' => $record['date'],
                ];
        }
    }
}
```

expected result:

```
[object_type] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
        
                [905] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                 [initiator_id] => 219
                                [object_id] => 905
                                [date] => 2021-11-16 04:53:58
                                [activity] => change


                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [initiator_id] => 219
                                [object_id] => 905
                                [date] => 2021-11-16 04:53:58
                                [activity] => change

                            )

                    )
                    
                    
                [917] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [initiator_id] => 219
                                [object_id] => 917
                                [date] => 2021-11-16 04:53:58
                                [activity] => change

                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [initiator_id] => 219
                                [object_id] => 917
                                [date] => 2021-11-16 04:53:58
                                [activity] => change
                    
                            )

                    )
                    
                    
            )

        [2] => Array
            (

                [925] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [initiator_id] => 925
                                [object_id] => 917
                                [date] => 2021-11-16 04:53:58
                                [activity] => change
                            )


                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: How should it act if `object_id` are all unique?

Comment: You want all the initiator_id, object_id, date "tuples" in the top level of a new array?

Comment: Justinas, if object_id are all unique .. it is new array level above. In one array put olny arrays with the same object_id.

Comment: Torbjörn Stabo, yes .. all data put in the top level of a new array if object_id not the same. In one array put only arrays with the same object_id.

Comment: I mean is it possible at index 1 for example to have Array of arrays by different object_id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply iterate over $arr and build a new array by putting each $arr item in its desired position:

```
$result = []; 
foreach($arr as $item) { 
    $result['object_type']
           [$item['object_type']]
           [$item['object_id']] []= $item; 
} 

print_r($result);
```

`[]=` means "add the right hand side to the array on the left hand side".

**Edit** Added object_id as 3rd level.

Comment: Torbjörn Stabo, from your example I do not inderstand how to achieve the goal with "In one array put only arrays with the same object_id" .. it dose not work. Could you show example please with my data?

Comment: @Roman It creates the same array as in the question. Are you saying you want something like `$result['object_type'][object_id]['initiator_id' => ..., 'object_id' => ..., 'date' => ...]`? I'm not sure I understand your desired output format.

Comment: I want to change a little current Array.. at first I want to divide data by object_type and then inside object_type divide by object_id .. it is important for me when I iterate this data to draw controls on frontend.

Comment: @Roman Ok. So if you have an object_id that appears more than once, which instance would you like to keep? The one with the most recent date?

Comment: Torbjörn Stabo, I do not want to delete any instance. All instance I need. Only to add key for example objects and sort arrays by the same object_id.

Comment: Like inside object_type I have only arrays with [object_type] => 1 for example and I want to have the same logic for object_id.

Comment: Do you want object id on the third level? ['object_type'][$object_type][$object_id]?

Comment: Also, there's still the question about what to do with objects with the same object_id. Do you want ['object_type'][$object_type][$object_id] to be an array with all the objects with that object id?

Comment: Torbjörn Stabo, I add add question expected result.

Comment: @Roman Ok, looks like my edited code then :). Except that the start index in your example is 1 but 0 with the code. Is that an issue?